# Promises in test cases in mocha and chai failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, es6-promise, chai

I am writing a test case in mocha and chai to check if the file is not present it will create the file. Following is the test case :

```
context('if the valid message is supplied and file is not present in the app\'s logs folder', () => {
  beforeEach((done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fs.exists(filePath, (exists) => {
        if (exists) {
          fileFound = true;
        } else {
          fileFound = false;
        }
      });
      done();
    }, 100);
  });

  it('should indicate the file is not present in the app\'s log folder', () => {
    expect(fileFound).to.be.false;
  });
  it('should create a new file in the app\'s log folder', () => {
    expect(fileFound).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Let's day file is present in the folder, in that case first test case should fail. But the problem is, it is saying expected undefined to be false, rather than expected true to be false.

Comment: It seems like you're creating a horrific mess of callback-based APIs and promises. Does `fs.exists` return a function? `.then()` only does anything useful when you pass a function to it.

Comment: This isn’t going to work the way you hope. It’s hard to know how to fix it without knowing more about `logs.errorLog()`. Does it return a promise or take a callback? How do you know when it’s finished writing the file?

Comment: fs.exist is a function to check whether the file is contained or not. Basically what I am trying to do with logs.errorLog the file will be created and then after the file creation I am checking if it exists or not, then after that thing is done I am checking the value of the variable.

Comment: logs.error creates a file, writes to the file and then throws an error.

Comment: As much as I love Promises, I don't really see any value in getting them involved just for this test. Why not just use the callbacks as callbacks? Mocha provides a `done` function specifically for that.

Comment: Hmm sounds good...can you give me a direction, how to fix this test case with the callback and done.

Comment: Again: how do you know when `logs.errorLog()` is finished writing the file?

Comment: let's say the file is already present and to check whether the file is present or not, I want to check. In that case, how can it be corrected. I have modified the code.

Comment: In that case you get rid of the promise that isn’t doing anything, put the `expect()` call inside the callback of `fs.exists()` and call `done()`.

Comment: yes, done with the solution but now having other problem. I have modified my code and question. Please help with that

Comment: Okay... where is `fileFound` declared? It looks like it is not in scope in your tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's very little point in using promises here. Your API is callback-based, so you should use a callback test.

Like this:

```
it('should exist', (done) => {
  fs.exists(filePath, (exists) => {
    expect(exists).to.be.true;

    done();
  });
});
```

One thing to bear in mind, mostly unrelated to your issue, is that [`fs.exists` is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) and you should use a different method like `fs.access` or `fs.stat`:

```
it('should exist', (done) => {
  fs.access(filePath, (err) => {
    expect(err).to.be.null;

    done();
  });
});
```

To address your *post edit* question, the problem here is that you are using `setTimeout` for no reason and calling `done` before `fs.exists` has a chance to finish.

The solution: get rid of the `setTimeout` and call `done` inside the `fs.exists` callback. You should also scope your `fileFound` variable at a place where it makes sense:

```
context('if the valid message is supplied and file is not present in the app\'s logs folder', () => {
  let fileFound;

  beforeEach((done) => {
    fs.exists(filePath, (exists) => {
      fileFound = exists;

      done();
    });
  });

  it('should indicate the file is not present in the app\'s log folder', () => {
    expect(fileFound).to.be.false;
  });
  it('should create a new file in the app\'s log folder', () => {
    expect(fileFound).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Comment: yups, that was the issue. changed it.